# NGINX server block configuration for hosting multiple websites on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualhost, wordpress

I want to host multiple wordpress websites on a Ubuntu 16.04 (Ubuntu-NGINX-MariaDB-PHP). I don't want to use wordpress multisite.

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps) . Everything is fine but I can host only one site. Whenever I created multiple server block configuration, it starts to show error and NGINX fail to start. I am not getting my config file correct. Here is the config file :

```
server {
     listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
     server_name abcde.org www.abcde.org;

     root /var/www/abcde;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php     index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

     location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
     }


     location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
     }
}
```

If I host only one website, it works fine. But as soon as I host the other website, NGINX fail to start. I use same config for both sites, after changing the server name and root directory.

Kindly guide me for the right configuration for NGINX server blocks.

Comment: Your config file looks to have mismatched brackets and just looks weird. Use my tutorial, it has sample config files to download. https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: This is just part of config file. No mismatch of brackets in actual file. I will go through your tutorial now. Thank you.

Comment: Good tutorial. Bookmarked it but it don't have what I want.

Comment: What if you copy-paste the exact same block with `server_name fghij.org www.fghij.org;`. Please post the error log when starting Nginx also

Comment: If `nginx` fails to start, what is the error message? Use `nginx -t` to test your configuration.

Comment: The tutorial goes through setting up six https websites on Nginx/AWS. It should have everything you need. You need to post complete configurations here if you want help, and you should get your indentation right in the post to make it easier for people to help you. You also need to post error messages and log entries as applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your nginx.config needs something like this line. This is what I do on my server

```
include /etc/nginx/enabled-sites/*;
```

In that directory you can have one file with many servers, or you can do what I do and have servers grouped by domain.

**File abcde.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.abcde.org;

  root /var/www/home;

  # Any locations you want. PHP example that I use below.
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
} # ends www.abcde.org server

# This server forwards to the www domain
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abcde.org;
  return 301 https://www.abcde.org$request_uri;
} # ends abcde.org server
```

**File example.conf**

```
# server for a completely separate domain
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;

  root /var/www/example;

  # Any locations you want
} # ends www.example.com server
```

**File default_server.conf**

```
# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't
# know which server block to send a request to
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  # This means "go away", effectively. You can also forward somewhere
  # or put default_server onto any of your server blocks.
  return      444; 
}
```